# how to refresh a page in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am completely new to inno setup.

I have an existing inno setup code which loads all the pages in the InitializeWizard(). I am trying to change the caption dynamically in the next page based on the radio button selected in the previous page.

```
 ExpandConstant('Special note for the Microsoft ' + SelectedSQLServerVersion + ' Setup')
```

Here the ***SelectedSQLServerVersion*** is a variable which holds the dynamic value from the previous page and I can see the value in log. I tried to load the page again and was expecting the variable will be replaced with the dynamic value in the second time, but it was empty. Is there any way to solve this.

Thanks in advance,
DeeJay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wizard pages have two common properties for the top bar labels, [`Caption`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage) and [`Description`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardPage). In your case you can update them e.g. when the page is just displayed, from the [`CurPageChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged) event:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
var
  MyPage: TWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  MyPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = MyPage.ID then
  begin
    MyPage.Caption := 'New caption';
    MyPage.Description := 'New description';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, @TLama Thanks for your quick response.I am still  getting 'Caption' and 'Description' in my page.                                                   PageSQLSetupFile := CreateInputFilePage(PageSQLSetupFile2,
  'Database Settings',
  'Caption',
  'Description');                                                                                      PageSQLSetupFile.Caption := 'Location of the Microsoft ' + SelectedSQLServerVersion + ' Setup ?';   (This is inside the CurPageChanged procedure)

Comment: With the example I posted ? That should work (at least I've tried it and worked).

Comment: 'Caption' and 'Description' are considered as string only and "PageSQLSetupFile.Caption" is showing unknown identifier when I debugged.

Comment: Well, let's start with what is that `PageSQLSetupFile` ?

Comment: 'PageSQLSetupFile' is my current page.

Comment: But what's the type of it ? You have declared a variable like `PageSQLSetupFile: ???` and I need to know the type I marked with `???` :) Or share your current script somehow (e.g. pastebin if you don't want to include it into the question) ...

Comment: PageSQLSetupFile: TInputFileWizardPage;

Comment: It is a wizard page class. So, that should just work. I'm afraid without seeing your code I won't help. If you run [`this script`](http://pastebin.com/BLwTqare), you should see the updated labels. And it's the minimal script to reproduce.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem there (but it's too little to say). Are you sure it is the right page you're looking at ? Couldn't that be e.g. `PageSQLSetupFile2` page ? Also note that you're conditionally updating either `Caption`, or `Description` (which looks like a mistake).

Comment: really appreciate your efforts. Can you look into my pastebin link again please? I have a function MSSQLSETUPDIR_CreatePage which is called in the InitializeWizard procedure? Is this creating any problems??

Comment: Hi TLama, it is working fine now. I have called the InitializeWizard procedure again which was creating issues. It works fine now. Thanks a ton!!!